# Adding elements from webpage to ArrayList in java

Tags: java, url, arraylist, html

I'm currently working on a project that involves analyzing weather information from various airports and weather stations. What I need to do is display the basic weather info from a url (example: http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KFHB.xml). Where I need to display temperature, visibility, etc. in some basic format. I was thinking an array list.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? How do I display the elements from a webpage onto a java application? What classes (methods, or other procedures) should I look into? Are there any good templates out there for this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can read through the contents of the url like reading a file doing the following:

```
URL url = new URL(link);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

You can also capture the RSS feed from that weather station. Read this article if you want an an example as how to parse a RSS feed:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/RSSFeed/article.html

Comment: Thanks this will get me started.